# connection between asp.net , c# and sql server ( both versions are 2012)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i wrote a connection string in asp.net i.e add 2 data through 2 textboxes into the sql server database . but after pressing submit button i face to an error .

**Details:**

**web.config:**

```
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myconectionstring"
    connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalogue=test;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

**code behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebApplication3
{

    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconectionstring"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

            try
            {
                ///string cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconectionstring"].ConnectionString;

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table_1 (name,fathername) VALUES('" + txt1.Text + "','" + txt2.Text + "')", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                String ErrorMsg = ex.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error message :**

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Keyword not supported: 'initial catalogue'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'initial catalogue'.

Source Error: 


Line 21:         {
Line 22:             string cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconectionstring"].ConnectionString;
Line 23:             SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
Line 24: 
Line 25:             try

Source File: c:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\WebForm1.aspx.cs    Line: 23
```

Comment: use `Initial Catalog` instead of `Initial Catalogue`

Comment: txt1.Text = "Robert'); DROP TABLE Table_1;--" fits nicely

Comment: Simple typographical error - should be closed.

Comment: Side note: It is recommended to use Parameterized Queries. As you are not using `SqlCommand.Parameters` your code clearly exposed to sql injections.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

And whenever you forgot a connection string of any database, go to:

http://www.connectionstrings.com

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string should start as follows:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;
```

instead of your current

```
data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalogue=test;
```

This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled Catalog wrong. Its
`Initial Catalog`

Answer (score 0):

its a type at `Initial Catalog` correct the spelling and it should work !!

for more information :-

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/